# Linqpad extension to plot graphs

Tags: linqpad

I tried to plot some graphs in Linqpad with with "Util.RawHtml()" and "Dump()" but it is not working with this [example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-data/) from amcharts.com. I created a string variable including all the HTML source code but the result is not working.

```
string html = "";
using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient ())
{
    html = client.DownloadString(@"http://pastebin.com/raw/pmMMwXhm");
}

Util.RawHtml(html).Dump();
```

Comment: Unfortunately `Util.RawHtml` has **very** strong validation on what it allows so it may not actually accept the html, even though it may be valid for a browser. Is it possible for you to produce an image instead? Also, be sure to explain what "not working" means. Do you get any results at all? An exception? Crash? Wrong output?

Answer (score 7):

Later versions of LinqPad 5 now support charting out of the box with `Util.Chart`. You can see the samples in the `Samples` Tab (next to `My Queries`) under

- `LINQPad Tutorial&Reference`

  - `Scratchpad Features`

    - `Charting with Chart`

The following script is the [*Chart() - dual scale* sample:](http://share.linqpad.net/kvpcbm.linq)

```
// Each y-series can have a different series type, and can be assigned to the secondary y-axis scale on the right.

var customers = new[]
{
    new { Name = "John", TotalOrders = 1000, PendingOrders = 50, CanceledOrders = 20 },
    new { Name = "Mary", TotalOrders = 1300, PendingOrders = 70, CanceledOrders = 25 },
    new { Name = "Sara", TotalOrders = 1400, PendingOrders = 60, CanceledOrders = 17 },
};

customers.Chart (c => c.Name)
    .AddYSeries (c => c.TotalOrders,    Util.SeriesType.Spline, "Total")
    .AddYSeries (c => c.PendingOrders,  Util.SeriesType.Column, "Pending",   useSecondaryYAxis:true)
    .AddYSeries (c => c.CanceledOrders, Util.SeriesType.Column, "Cancelled", useSecondaryYAxis:true)
    .Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this will not work because the html contains scripts that will not be executed.

As an alternative, you can still use the old (and deprecated) google charts api, eg

```
var link = @"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y&chbh=a&chs=300x225&cht=bvg&chco=A2C180,3D7930&chd=t:10,20,30,40,50,60|30,35,40,45,55,60&chtt=Sample";

Util.Image (link).Dump();
```

or see 
http://blog.divebomb.org/2012/11/dumping-charts-in-linqpad/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the answer you're after but there may be value in looking at the `DisplayWebPage` method on the `Util` class in Linqpad.  This correctly rendered your chart in the result window, (although there was a script error).  Obviously, this may not solve your underlying issue.

I used version 5.10.00 to test this.